# Can I add a subcolumn to a hive struct column using alter table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've a very complex table structure in hive, let's say that it's like the following table:

```
create table dirceu ( a struct<b:string,c:string>);
```

Now I do need to add another subcolumn to the a column, and it should have the structure b,c and d, I'm trying to do it with the following alter table:

```
alter table dirceu change column a a struct<b:string,c:string, d:string>;
```

But this throw the following error:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. The following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in their respective positions :
a (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Is there a way to do this using alter table? I know that I can do it using create table and copy the data, but I would like to know if there is another way to do it.
 **UPDATE**
I'm using hive: 2.1.0.2.6.1.0-129
HortonWorks: HDP-2.6.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This is the command you need to give,

```
ALTER TABLE dirceu CHANGE COLUMN a a STRUCT<b:STRING, c:STRING, d:STRING>;
```

You can't add a new field to Collection data type. Instead, you need to completely change the schema. 
Hope you like the answer. Yippee!!

Comment: Hello Krishna thanks for answering this question, but this code didn't worked here. Unable to alter table. The following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in their respective positions: a (state=08S01,code=1)

Comment: Oh! it worked for me perfectly. Might you have a problem with the distribution. Try working on different system, and let me know, if problem still persists.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it works by this command,

```
alter table dirceu add column a struct<d:string>;
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work by comment.

Comment: Hi John, it didn't worked Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 cannot recognize input near 'add' 'column' 'a' in alter table statement (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: @John Deer You need to update the schema. It doesn't work by "add" command.

Comment: Oh! Thanks @DSaiKrishna

Comment: @dirceusemighini and D Sai Krishna I have a problem with this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322547/error-importing-dataset-in-hive) Can you please help me?

Comment: You can't remove a field after it's added to a complex type.

More information can be found here:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/How-to-add-a-field-to-a-complex-type-in-Alter-Table/td-p/38068