# Error importing dataset in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have a dataset as follows,

```
John  Doe^A100000.0^AMary  Smith^BTodd  Jones^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A1 Michigan Ave.^BChicago^BIL^B60600
Mary  Smith^A80000.0^ABill  King^AFederal  Taxes^C.2^BState Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A100 Ontario St.^BChicago^BIL^B60601 Todd Jones^A70000.0^AFederal Taxes^C.15^BState Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.1^A200 Chicago Ave.^BOak Park^BIL^B60700
Bill  King^A60000.0^AFederal  Taxes^C.15^BState  Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.1^A300 Obscure Dr.^BObscuria^BIL^B60100
```

I have read in Hive documentation on "Text Encoding of Data values" on how hive decodes dataset having different "delimiters". For the above dataset, I have created a table with following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
name STRING,
salary FLOAT,
subordinates ARRAY<STRING>,
deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
address STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

But the dataset is not being imported properly into the table.

```
|employees.name|employees.salary|employees.subordinates|employees.deductions|employees.address|
|--------------|----------------|----------------------|--------------------|-----------------|
|John  Doe|NULL|["AMary  Smith"]|{"BTodd  Jones":null}|("street":"AFederal Taxes","city":null,"state":null,"zip":null}|
|Mary  Smith|NULL|["ABill  King"]|{"AFederal  Taxes":null}|{"street":"C.2","city":null,"state":null,"zip":null}|
|Bill  King|NULL|["AFederal  Taxes"]|{"C.15":null}|{"street":"BState  Taxes","city":null,"state":null,"zip":null} |
```

Can anyone please explain me why this is getting wrong though I am following as per [documentation example in Page 45](http://www.reedbushey.com/99Programming%20Hive.pdf)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never loaded a table from text file in this way, I always use spark to manipulate the data before saving. This may be related to your local way to format the float (does your system, by default, use . to separate decimals) or it could be a hive Bug, which version of hive are you using?

Comment: My hive version is `Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0)`. Will reporting the problem in GitHub community help me?

Comment: Have you tried the mailing list?